# JDBC Appender does not write exception stack trace

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j2

We use log4j2 and have two appenders: The `Console`-Appender and a `JDBC`-Appender.
The `Console`-Appender **does** correctly log full stack traces of exceptions; however, the `JDBC`-Appender does only log the exception itself, without stack trace. According our config, it should also write full trace: `pattern="%throwable{50}`

Here is our `log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test" status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false" >
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <JDBC name="DatabaseAppender" tableName="logentry" ignoreExceptions="false" >
            <ConnectionFactory class="....LoggingConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <Column name="eventDate" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false"/>
            <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false"/>
            <Column name="message" pattern="%message" isUnicode="false"/>
            <Column name="exception" pattern="%throwable{50}" isUnicode="false"/>
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${env:LOG_LEVEL}">
            <AppenderRef ref="DatabaseAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What is wrong?
There are some similar posts here; but they target log4j1 or not JDBC Appender. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
 - badera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the this configuration should capture the first 50 lines of the full stack trace. I looked at the code but couldn't find anything obvious that might cause this. You may have found a bug. Please raise this on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker.

Can you provide more detail: what database (and version) are you using? What is the SQL type of the column you want to store the exception in?

Also, have you tried with just `%throwable` without limiting the number of lines?

Comment: Thank you, Remko! if I use just `%throwable`, it works fine! I will raise an issue. We use PostgreSQL 9.4.x and 9.5.x (does not matter which one and which minors; the behavior is the same). The type of column `exception` is `character varying`.

Comment: Great, glad my answer was useful to you!